# how to access viewdata value in script using jquery in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how to access `viewdata` value in script using `jquery` in `mvc 4`.

I new to `mvc` ,I am not getting the view data value to javascript. I tried

```
var data = "@ViewData["notify"]";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["notify"]));
```

More:

- [Json.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
- [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to debug this? I'm using jQuery v2.2.1, and it says, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`